# How to output only the post content

Tags: the-content

How can I output ONLY the post content (ie the text entered into the wysiwyg) and nothing else? i just need this for the posts in a specific category, so if i could call like say,

```
<?php get_template_part( 'venue_content', 'single' ); ?>
```

it would be ideal.

Comment: you should mark chip's answer as accepted -- that way people will know you're not still looking for one when they scan the list of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in the loop, or otherwise know (or know how to get) the `$post` object:

```
function wpse63358_get_post_content() {
    global $post;
    return $post->post_content;
}
```

If you want the *formatted* post content, replace this:

```
return $post->post_content;
```

...with this:

```
return apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
```

To echo the function output:

```
echo wpse63358_get_post_content();
```

#### Edit

Note: if you just want to output post content in the template, you don't actually even have to bother with wrapping it in a function. Simply use:

```
global $post;
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
```

Comment: Or the single template for the OP's 'venue_content' could simply contain the line `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );`

Comment: @marfarma yes, of course; but I based my answer on the wording of the title: "*how can i write a **function** that returns ONLY the post body*". :)

Comment: chip - I tried yours and couldn't figure out how to get it to work; not your fault, mine, for not being so familiar with altering default wordpress functionality. :)

Comment: @jamie: you would define that function in `functions.php`, and then *call it* wherever you want the post content to output - i.e. *wherever you currently have* `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );`. But that said, it would probably be more accurate to update the wording of the question/title.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use 'Post formats' for this, either the aside or the quote format I believe displays just the main content - http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats

Comment: cool, that is new to me, i'll definitely check it out!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output only the post content, excluding any shortcodes, try something like this.

```
global $post;
$postContentStr = apply_filters('the_content', strip_shortcodes($post->post_content));
echo $postContentStr;
```