# how to output HTML tags in post_content and not as plain text

Tags: filters, pages, html

Currently I have a post with `<strong>` and `<em>` tags, and `<p>` tags. But they all seem to be being outputted as plain text, and not formatted HTML

I am using laravel blade as my templating engine. I currently have:

```
@php
   $page = get_page_by_title( 'Test Page' );
   $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $page->post_content );
@endphp
```

Which outputs:

```
<p>This is a test page for development practice.</p> <p>Here is another line etc</p> <p><strong>BOLD TEXT</strong></p> <p><em>ITALIC TEXT</em></p>
```

When it needs to be:

> This is a test page for development practice.
>
> Here is
>   another line etc
>
> **BOLD TEXT**
>
> *ITALIC
>   TEXT*

This answer:
[How to output only the post content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63358/how-to-output-only-the-post-content?newreg=acd1207674a046e19d5d0c7cbd9833d4c) suggests to use `apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );` which is what I'm currently doing

how do you have content outputted as HTML and not plain text?

Comment: Are you entering tags into the editor while it's still in the visual mode? Or are you editing blocks in HTML? Are you absolutely sure this isn't Laravel Blade auto-escaping things? WordPress doesn't do Laravel blade templates out of the box. `the_content` filter is intended for processing shortcodes and OEmbeds, etc, it has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: crap, didn't think about blade/laravel getting involved. good point, thanks.